# Which one of these is better for ASP.NET Access database for forum

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql, ms-access

Is it better to have 1 table with 10 000 entries, or is it better to have 100 tables with 100 entries.
The idea is to create a table for each thread created, that table is to store all the posts for the thread. It was sugested to me to have one master table for all entries of all threads, and when I open a specific thread to call just the entries for that table (e.g. by ID of thread)

Comment: One table per forum thread?  No.  Define your entities (thread, post, comment, etc.) and define tables to store those entities.  Don't duplicate the same entity type across multiple tables.  And don't dynamically create tables as part of the normal logic of an otherwise very simple system.  A static database schema is *much* easier to work with than a dynamic one.  (Note also that "10,000 entries" is a *very* small amount of data.  You're not gaining any performance by making the system more complicated this way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance wise there should be little (if any at all) difference.

Logically and rationally, however, creating a table for each and every thread makes no sense. It makes much more sense to have a table for threads (i.e.: thread name and thread ID relationship, created date, etc.) and using that thread ID as a foreign key in a table for posts (i.e.: post ID and the thread ID to which it belongs).

Of course in the end it won't matter much, unless your forum begins to grow to a considerable size (5,000+ regular users).